# Monitoramento em tempo real usando GPS

Tags: ios, objective-c, maps, gps

Estou criando um app para um pizzaria em que o cliente pode ver a localização do motoboy que irá entregar sua pizza em tempo real, mas surgiu uma duvida, eu gostaria de saber como faço para enviar minha localização através de um web service a cada 15 segundos sem atraso, qual mapa devo usar em um painel para monitorar o os apps?

Comment: Você pode usar o [`CoreLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/) para capturar a localização do celular e enviar para o servidor a cada 15 segundos, no seu painel pode usar o [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/) ou outro qualquer.

Comment: Qual versão do mapa devo usar que não esteja descontinuada e como faço para fazer com o mapa atualize sem precisar recarregar toda a pagina novamente?

Comment: Você pode fazer uma consulta a cada 15 segundos no painel e atualizando o ponto no mapa, aconselho usar sempre a última versão pois ela é mais completa e tem novos recursos (caso necessite usa-los)

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: ja olhou SignaIR e SignaIR pra iOS?

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada @Rafael Gonçalves, muito obrigado amigo.